# How to find location of an object in java(RCP)?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have a location where it will have treeitem.
I need to point my mouse focus to the location where the treeitem is being set.
I need java code to find the location of the pointer and set focus on the item.

```
Robot r = new Robot();
r.mouseMove(x,y);
```

I need to find x and y which is the location of the particular object to set the focus.
Kindly assist

Comment: Do you actually have the SWT `TreeItem`? For testing SWT code [swtbot](https://www.eclipse.org/swtbot/) might be a better choice.

Comment: yes TreeItem only I am having. i ll try swtbot